# Problem with Scaling Functions

Tags: plotting, scaling

I'm trying to build a `BarChart` off of a table of discrete data. I would like to use `ScalingFunctions`. Not working. Here is my code:

```
StepPyramid04 = BarChart[{WDscrt4},
  ChartElementFunction->"ObliqueRectangle",
  ScalingFunctions->{"Log2",None},
  ChartStyle->{Red,Red,Red,Green,Green,Green,Green,Green,Green,Green,Green,Green,Green,Green,Green,Green,Blue,Blue,Blue,Blue},
  ChartLabels->{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"},
  AspectRatio->2/\[Pi],
  GridLines->Automatic,
  BarSpacing->Automatic,
  AxesLabel->Automatic
]
```

My error message reads:

```
Visualization`Utilities`ScalingDump`mhead::sclfn: The scaling function {Log2,None} cannot 
be used to scale coordinates.
```

Advice? Suggestions?

Comment: Why not just `ScalingFunctions -> "Log2"`?

Comment: OKCarl, may I suggest that you revisit [your 13 questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/44937/okcarl?tab=questions) and see if any answers are worth accepting/upvoting?

Answer (score 5):

For two dimensional functions,

```
ScalingFunctions -> "Log2"
```

is equivalent to

```
ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log2"}
```

In `BarChart`, though, this is not the case. `BarChart` effectively has only one axis, used to measure the bar heights with. So, using either

```
ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log2"}
```

or

```
ScalingFunctions -> {"Log2", None}
```

will generate that message.

```
ScalingFunctions -> {"Log2"}
```

works, though.

Comment: Thank you Mister rcollyer. Your last option works.

Comment: @OKCarl this site's "currency" is upvotes and accepted answers. The accepted answers, in particular, are needed to highlight the work, presenting it to others as useful/canonical. Yet, for none of your questions have you marked any of the answers as accepted, despite you comment, above. Please, if you find them useful, mark the best as accepted.